# QoS User Bandwidth Management

Tags: networking

Redesigning for an old friend a Small-sized ISP (around 30-40 users). Though am not well versed Full-time Linux techie, but extensively work on Cisco's FTTH infrastructure, Routers, BRAS, DSLAM and STB for homes with just little knowledge and experience on Linux only through research.

I had intially setup traffic shaping a couple months ago when he started, using tc htb and iptables on Linux for bandwidth shaping on the outgoing interface which works perfectly well. For downloading we had setup Squid Caching Proxy with delay pools for large downloads that too works well when shaping is disabled.

Problem is recently his users started nagging about the performance issues on the service though total bandwidth utilization is only 1/2 of the 8Mbps Download. Just to give you an example with one of the user package,

```
Current 
Package (1 Mb)
Download: Rate 128Kbit Ceil 1024Kbit, SFQ Leaf enabled
Upload: Shared 1Mb, no limit
```

Problem starts espacially if 2 or more users on a single PPPoE session of 128 Kbit, when streaming multiple videos, I.e. YouTube, Facebook, Vimeo / voice or voip, I.e. Skype or Jabber/Xmpp users and/or multiple torrent downloads at a single time

**Q1.** Is it possible to shape user bandwidth like Cisco's like QoS, PWFQ - per session queueing, I.e.

```
Rate 128Kbit Ceil 128Kbit
Queue 1 32Kbit Ceil 32Kbit; prio 0; voice,video,voip,gaming
Queue 2 16Kbit Ceil 128Kbit; prio 1; ssh,dns,ftp,irc 
Queue 3 64Kbit Ceil 128Kbit; prio 2; http,https,mail,slingbox
Queue 4 16Kbit Ceil 128Kbit; prio 3; torrents,etc
```

-- or --

```
Rate 128Kbit Burst 256Kbit
Queue 1 32Kbit Ceil 32Kbit; prio 0; voice,video,voip,gaming
Queue 2 16Kbit Ceil 128Kbit; prio 1; ssh,dns,ftp,irc 
Queue 3 64Kbit Ceil 128Kbit; prio 2; http,https,mail,slingbox
Queue 4 16Kbit Ceil 128Kbit; prio 3; torrents,etc
```

-- or --

```
Rate 256Kbit Ceil 1024Kbit with QoS as above
```

Have looked online a lot, but mostly mentioning the above on shaping outgoing. We currently can't test the above scenarios as all servers are in production and can't be mingled or played around with.

**Q2.** Also, How would we shape user upload limit, that is

```
(1 Mb Down / 128 Kb Upload)
Rate 64Kbit Ceil 128Kbit
```

any suggestions/improvement the above welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: It was a pleasure to read the question. Thanks!

Comment: Users on a 128 kbit connection are having trouble running multiple video streams? Is this is a serious question?